# Program to convert time in seconds to hh:mm:ss format

Tags: vb.net, time-format

I am trying to make a simple program to convert time given in seconds to hh:mm:ss format. But for some particular input values it produces an incorrect time format. This is what I have tried:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Hours, Minutes, Seconds As Integer

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
        lblHours.Text = "00"
        lblMinutes.Text = "00"
        lblSeconds.Text = "00"
        txtTimeSeconds.Text = ""
        txtFormattedTime.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate1.Click
        Seconds = Integer.Parse(txtTimeSeconds.Text)
        Hours = Seconds / 3600
        Seconds = Seconds Mod 3600
        Minutes = Seconds / 60
        Seconds = Seconds Mod 60

        lblHours.Text = Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
        lblMinutes.Text = Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
        lblSeconds.Text = Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)

        txtFormattedTime.Text = Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It works when the input value is 30:

[image]

It does not work when the input value is 31:

[image]

What have I done wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is class in .NET called [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which makes your code easy and elegant.

Example:

```
dim iSecond as double = 0 'Total number of seconds
Dim iSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iSecond)

lblHours.Text = iSpan.Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
lblMinutes.Text = iSpan.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
lblSeconds.Text = iSpan.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)

txtFormattedTime.Text = iSpan.Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
                        iSpan.Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & _
                        iSpan.Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

Answer (score 9):

Visual Basic has *two* division operators, `/` and `\`.  The / operator produces a result that's of type Double.  You calculate 31 / 60 = 0.51666...  You next assign that result to an Integer, that requires rounding.  Thus producing 1, not 0.

You want to use the `\` operator, the integer division operator.  It truncates the result.

Comment: Seems to me that this is the real answer, describing exactly what goes wrong and presenting a solution to it. +1!

Answer (score 6):

I hope this code will be useful

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(227) 'or --> Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 227, 0)

Dim mydate As DateTime = New DateTime(ts.Ticks)
MessageBox.Show(mydate.ToString(("HH:mm:ss")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using integers to store your data but division gives you doubles. When converting it back to integers it gets rounded to the nearest round number. So 0.5 becomes 0 but 0.51 becomes 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim SecondsDifference as integer = 2500  
Dim hms = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecondsDifference)
Dim h = hms.Hours.ToString
Dim m = hms.Minutes.ToString
Dim s = hms.Seconds.ToString
MsgBox("Hour:" + h + " Min:" + m + " Sec:" + s)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the **txtformattedtime.text=...** I think *"ispan.tostring"* would work as well.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

I know this one has already been answered for a while now, but I thought I might share my solution to the problem at hand.  If you place the number of seconds in a `TimeSpan` object, you can quite easily extract the days, hours, minutes, seconds and even fractional seconds directly using `TimeSpan.toString()` method.  Using an identical form and object names, I used the following code to achieve the desired results.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    lblHours.Text = "00"
    lblMinutes.Text = "00"
    lblSeconds.Text = "00"
    txtTimeSeconds.Text = ""
    txtFormattedTime.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim tsSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(txtTimeSeconds.Text))
    lblHours.Text = tsSeconds.ToString("hh")
    lblMinutes.Text = tsSeconds.ToString("mm")
    lblSeconds.Text = tsSeconds.ToString("ss")
    txtFormattedTime.Text = tsSeconds.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub
End Class
```

Visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on the method used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ToFormattedHour(ByVal seconds As Long) As String
    Dim hours As Long, minutes As Long

    hours = seconds \ 3600
    seconds = seconds Mod 3600

    minutes = seconds \ 60
    seconds = seconds Mod 60

    Return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours, minutes, seconds)
End Function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).